# pack and unpack at the right format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pack, unpack

I'm looking to unpack from a buffer a string and its length.

For example to obtain `(4, 'Gégé')` from this buffer :
`b'\x00\x04G\xE9g\xe9'`

Does someone know how to do ?

Comment: Please do not delete your question when it has received a (useful) answer.

Answer (score 4):

The length data looks like a big-endian unsigned 16 bit integer, and the string data looks like it's using the Latin1 encoding. If that's correct, you can extract it like this:

```
from struct import unpack

def extract(buff):
    return unpack(b'>H', buff[:2])[0], buff[2:].decode('latin1')

buff = b'\x00\x04G\xE9g\xe9'
print(extract(buff))
```

**output**

```
(4, 'Gégé')
```

Another possibility for the encoding is the old [Windows code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which can be decoded using `.decode('cp1252')`.

---

The above code works in both Python 2 & Python 3. But in Python 3 there's an easier way: we don't need `struct.unpack`, we can use the [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) method.

```
def extract(buff):
    return int.from_bytes(buff[:2], 'big'), buff[2:].decode('latin1')
```